# Is there a way to combine independent functions of a page into single and query once to distribute fetched data individually

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**First of all,** it's an idea, need to share because its solution is not present to me. But if applicable, it can help many PHP developer as well.

I'm developing a WordPress Ad Manager Plugin. Very simple thought, get an image URL into db with an id, and fetch the URL and show them with `<img>` tag. In my show ad function I did something like this:

```
<?php
function show_ad($id){
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "my_ad";

    $query = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT *
            FROM $table
            WHERE id = $id;
            ");
   $output = echo '<img src="'. $query[0]->img_url .'"/>';
   return $output;
}
?>
```

The ad can be shown by any of these ways: PHP Function in Template (`<?php show_ad($); ?>`), Shortcode, Sidebar Widget. In all the cases the image showing process will be the same function.

Suppose, I have a site, where I added 20 ads into the plugin db. Now I want to show 10 of them into 10 different places, 10 different `<div>`s. in the same page. So what the function is doing, using the same function in 10 different places means **10 Individual db Queries**. And 10 db Queries means 10 times hit to db.

So, I'm seeking a way to combine all the function into one and execute a single db query to fetch data. I'm dreaming something like the following. Assuming there are 10 different ad places in my page:

```
<?php
// A TOTAL FICTIONOUS CODE BLOCK
if( function_in_this_page_exists( 'show_ad' ) ) {
   $function_array = make_them_array_with_vallues();

   //so function_array looks like: array( '2','4','1','5','8','10','15', ... )

   //execute the combined query function
   //and query the db once
   $query_result_array = combined_query_function();

   //so the $query_result_array looks like: array('2'=>'http://url2.com','4'=>'http://url4.com','1'=>'http://url1.com', ...)

   //now, distribute the data to the individual function where they are
   //by executing another function that distribute fetched data where their id belongs
   distribute_array_data_to_functions($query_result_array);
}
?>
```

Though it's a fictionous code block, but [if possible], with this way a simple db query can do all the individual queries instead. I don't think such a function-fetching-with-parameter thing is present now in PHP. Any idea?

Comment: Don't worry about this pre-optimization where most likely all you're saving is protocol overhead, only to complicate the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you might use the MySQL keyword IN to fetch more than one id.

Secondly, just write your processing function for the returned data-set as you imagined.
In other words, build the content, insert image URL for each for the ids.

After that, you might think about caching the query and caching the generated content.

```
$array_with_ids = array('1','2','3');

$sql = 'SELECT * 
      FROM `table` 
     WHERE `id` IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $array)) . ')';
```

Comment: Thanks for the query part. But you missed the other two parts I think: **"Is there a way to combine independent functions of a page into single"** & **"distribute fetched data individually"**.

Comment: ok. combine functions by calling show_ad(id), where id is then stored into an array. on the footer of your page call get_all_ads(), which does the query for all of the stored ids of show_ad().             next part: get_all_ads() returns the mysql result set. again use the ids array to iterate over it and generateAdContent(). now, you need to insert that content, use buffered page with placeholders to replace ad_placeholder_id, which might do a method insertAd(). then render the complete page to the browser.

Comment: Thanks. Got your answer. But can't understand the whole. May be because of my lack in PHP knowledge. I'll talk about it with a PHP developer with your answer. Let's see...

Comment: Feel free to ask! I will elaborate a bit more on this, maybe that helps: The strategy is to first buffer the ids, until you have them all. Then you would do the mysql request with them. After that you will work on the mysql result to generate your content. This content is then inserted into the page via a simple string replace. This strategy also allows exchanging the mysql request against a caching layer request.

Comment: It'd be better to not misusing the comment area. If anything you think can provide the answer to the Question more elaborately, you can add them to the Answer by editing that. And thanks for your assistance, and interest in this thought. I appreciate that. I'd love to learn the technique from you. :)